# Is it possible to export (from SqlServer 2008 to Visio 2010) ERD of the database?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get ERD of the database in Visio, but unsuccessfully. I tried reverse engineering option in Visio also, but unsuccessfully.

Did anyone do this already? How?

Comment: I used some tool in the past capable of doing such thing

I believe TOAD can do the same 

most probably it will not be as part of the standard clients provided by the database engine itself, however in third party you can find that

Comment: I tried TOAD, although I did not have to (because I solved my problem). I like it a lot. Recommend for anyone who is bored with SQL Server Management Studio looks.

Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I did it using Visio 2010, at last. "Reverse Engineer"  option in "Database" menu works after all. I was not creating datasource properly. I used "File Data Source" option, instead of "User Data Source" in New Data Source wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with a coworker, and she said SQL Management Studio does not provide the function of extracting ERD.

that means you have to use some third party application

Comment: Didn't have to, I succeeded with Visio, thanks anyway